# How do you remove a specific row in array in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the dataframe below

```
           Date                   Country  Death_Count
0    2021-05-30                     Macau          NaN
1    2021-05-30                 Hong Kong          NaN
2    2021-05-30     Saint Kitts and Nevis          0.0
3    2021-05-30             New Caledonia          0.0
4    2021-05-30              Turkmenistan          0.0
..          ...                       ...          ...
209  2021-05-30                      Peru     184582.0
210  2021-05-30                    Mexico     230835.0
211  2021-05-30                     India     331895.0
212  2021-05-30                    Brazil     461931.0
213  2021-05-30  United States of America     588756.0
```

[214 rows x 3 columns]

Here is the part of my code

```
#Rename Header
data.columns =["Date","Country","Death Count"]

#View empty value
print(data.isnull())

#Fill the empty value
data=data.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)

#Replace / Fill NaN Value with 0
data.fillna(0)

#Removing empty row
data = data.dropna(axis=0)
''''''
```

and what's happening is that it only remove the 2 rows that are converted from NaN to 0. How do I include other rows that has 0 value in the first place? I'm new in python programming

Comment: So you want to remove all rows where death count is 0?

Comment: `data.fillna(0)` here you're not assigning the result back to the original df. `data.dropna(axis=0)` and this will look for `NaN` values and drop those not `0`

Comment: This question is about using numpy, which is a library separate from python. In the future you should tag it appropriately and also mention this in the post and header

Comment: Not to be picky but the library you are using is pandas not numpy. You might receive more help if you label and tag the post correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
data = data.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)
data = data.fillna(0)
data = data.mask(data.eq(0)).dropna(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, is the code "data.eq(0)" is the one who looks to the data that has a value of 0? and "data = data.mask(data.eq(0)).dropna(axis=0)" is it the same as `data = data.mask(data.eq(0))` `data = data.dropna(axis=0)` ?